# what does "establishment" imply in the following context

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

> The proposal includes considerable renovations to the gallery with an extension of exhibition space and the ***establishment*** of more permanent areas for exhibiting.

What does the word *establishment* connote here exactly? The usage seems to be kinda out of place, irrelevant, while considering the context and architectural register as well, so would want to know what do you think about it?

Answer (score 2):

The first meaning of *establishment* in the OED is " 1. The action of establishing; the fact of being established: in various senses of the vb.".

Meaning 3 of *establish* is " 3. To set up on a secure or permanent basis; to found (a government, an institution; in mod. use often, a house of business)."

Comment: did you mean *to build* or *construct something* by  **set up**? because I assume this verb is generally used to imply constructing/installing rather small structures, like : *setting up camp* . Is it used to refer to the making of big structures like rooms or houses?

Comment: No, _establish_ is not usually used for physically constructing anything at all. It is used for creating something notional, such as an institution, or (here) an exhibition space. The galleries so established will presumably need some physical modification, but that is not what is meant by _establishing_ them.

Comment: actually I'd never want to bother anyone any longer by belaboring the subject that much, I nearly got the point but there may be times that we learners so long to enter straight into the natives' brains to know or make sure what a word exactly connotes in them and *establish*  is probably one of them.  so, in order to make sure that what I think is what you think about it, just let me know, how would you reword *establishment* by the closest meaning regarding the context?

Comment: In the context, I would probably use "creation", because if the proposal is about renovations to the gallery, it probably does include whatever building work would be needed on those areas. But that is from context, not implicit in the work "establishment". In other contexts, the meaning might be little more than "designation of more permanent areas for exhibition".